# Android won't launch Facebook Messenger intent from an NFC tag URL

Tags: android, facebook, nfc, facebook-messenger

I'm working with NFC tags and trying to launch a Facebook Messenger link off the scan. I've written some php that detects the user agent and redirects to an Android intent or launches the app on iOS.

The problem is the app simply won't launch on Android when scanning the tag - I get a blank white page in Chrome.

It works 100% of the time for iOS and if I simply browse to the page in Chrome, but never from a tag scan. Here's the process:

NFC tag holds the URL: https://mytestsite_dot_com/go.php

Page detects user gent and redirects to Android intent or iOS app launch, with fallback to the messenger m.me URL

**URL:** https://m.me/[PAGE-ID]
redirects fine when browsing direct to page, or button/link click
does not work from NFC scan

**Android intent:** intent://user/[PAGE-ID]/#Intent;scheme=fb-messenger;package=com.facebook.orca;end
redirects fine browsing direct to page, or button/link click
does not work from NFC scan

**iOS app launch:** fb-messenger-public://user-thread/[PAGE-ID]
works 100%

Is there any to get the redirect to work on Android? Otherwise, I've got to display an interim landing page and have the user click a button to continue if they're on Android.